# Python - Add a column to each dataframe of a Pandas Panel

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a panel with of dataframes, indexed by `code`. For instance `panel["ABC"]` gives me the dataframe of "ABC", which is basically a NxM matrix of data.

Now, I also have a dictionary `dict`, mapping each `code` to a number. I want to add a new column to each of my dataframes, containing the corresponding number (repeated each row).

What is the best way to achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way, but I would do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Item1' : pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3)), 'Item2' : pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3))}

p = pd.Panel(data)

d = {'Item1':1, 'Item2':2}

for key, values in d.iteritems():

    p[key]['newcol'] = values

    print p[key]
```

This returns something like:

```
          0         1         2  newcol
0  1.348574 -1.141693  0.630736       2
1 -0.569502 -2.754901 -0.541633       2
2 -0.365106  0.087317  0.292110       2
3 -0.481947  0.719049 -0.216578       2

          0         1         2  newcol
0  1.622063  1.365436  1.701292       1
1 -0.050607 -2.451337 -1.053154       1
2  0.414793  0.295848 -0.206926       1
3  1.669253 -1.648159 -0.903917       1
```

EDIT: you can build a new panel with the updated dataframe with:

```
newd = {}

for key, values in d.iteritems():

     p[key]['newcol'] = values

     # Add new keys and dataframe to a new dictionary
     newd[key] = p[key]
```

and then build a new Panel:

```
p2 = pd.Panel(newd)
```

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks for your reply. I tried your suggestion already, but the problem is that the new column "disappears" after the for loop as finished.
How can I make these new columns stay there?

Comment: @Abramodj Do you have to store them again on the panel?

Comment: Yes I do. Btw, I figured out that it "disappears" only if I use iloc to access the panel.Using keys, it works as expected. Why?!